# How can I connect to DashDB with Slick?

Tags: playframework, ibm-cloud, slick, dashdb, frm

I have a Scala Play application running on Bluemix. We decided to try [DashDB](http://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/technology/cloud-data-services/dashdb/) (we were on DB2 before).

The application uses the [freeslick](https://github.com/smootoo/freeslick) plugin for connection to DB2 which worked fine. It also seems to partly work (SELECT queries work, UPDATE not) with DashDB. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: why was this voted to be closed without any comment?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some documentation on how to connect IBM or third party applications to dashDB

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_from_external_applications.html

I don't know much about freeslick plugin but if you are able to connect to DB2 , what is the error you are running into to connect to dashDB ? The connection information is available in your dashDB service bluemix page.